# cant install/uninstall more than 5 dictionaries at once

Tags: apt, dictionary

I tried to install all freedict packages at once and it kept timing out every five dictionaries.

is there anyway to rememdy this? for example after installing every 5 packages, give apt a timeout.

EDIT: I do not think trying a different mirror is gonna help.

when I try to install more than 5 freedict packages, there is an error from dict daemon server saying I am making too many changes too fast.

I need a way to tell apt to install packages not all at once. either through batches of installation or through waiting between unpacking and setting up packages. the solution does not have to be apt only

Comment: Review the apt configuration options in `man apt.conf`

Comment: I read it, what part of it is the one you think would help?

Comment: Nothing. It's not a problem the apt developers considered, so there is no configuration for it. You have now seen that for yourself. It might be an issue with the freedict server applications. Your best bet is to install in small batches that don't overwhelm the server, and those batches must be created by you (not by apt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to @user535733 it cannot be done.

Comment: Well, it cannot be done *the way you proposed* by telling apt to throttle the install process.